# I'm looking to replicate reports that similar-looking to these. Any ideas how it can be done?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, latex

Reports like these:

http://www3.weforum.org/docs/WEF_GlobalRisks_Report_2014.pdf

https://www.bmwgroup.com/content/dam/bmw-group-websites/bmwgroup_com/ir/downloads/en/2016/BMW_GB16_en_Finanzbericht.pdf

With an index, organized, nice tables and figures, captivating fonts and colors, etc.

Anybody know how can it be done? (which software?, etc. )

Comment: Looking at the PDF properties, both were made in InDesign. The first one in CS6 and the second one in CC (2014).

Answer (score 4):

Any professional-level layout software can do this (InDesign, XPress, FrameMaker).

Even some less-than-ideal tools may be able to pull it off (Word, Pages, etc) with enough effort.

The key requirement is a designer with an eye for layout and typography usage, as well as knowledge of the software in use.

No software will handle the aesthetic aspects for you.

This is kind of like asking "I need software that will paint the Mona Lisa or Starry Night" -- there are a million applications capable of "painting" but none will replicate DaVinci or Van Gogh's eye for color and brush strokes. Quality art (i.e. Layout) takes an artist.